# Add subview to tableview which doesn't scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I'm using a UITableViewController and want to add a searchbar.

My options are `[self.tableview addSubview:searchBar]` or `self.tableview.tableHeaderView = searchBar`
Both options will scroll the searchbar along the rest of the tableview, which I understand. But is there a way to lock elements up, instead of using a UIViewController or changing the frame origin on scroll?
I'm thinking of a way to get above the current view hierarchy and add a subview onto that.

I tried the opposite approach, to add a view to the superview and bring that to front

`[[self.tableView superview] addSubview:searchBar];
 [[self.tableView superview] bringSubviewToFront:searchBar];`
}

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITableViewControllers` are `UIViewControllers` that have their main view property being an `UITableView`. Thus this `UITableView` do takes all the screen.

The approach you are looking for is to use a standard `UIViewController` whose view is a standard `UIView`, and add your `UISearchBar` and the `UITableView` as a subview to it in IB.

To do this, simply:

- Change the class of your view controller and instead mention that it conforms to the tableview-associated protocols : change `@interface UITableViewController` to `@interface UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`
- Add a `@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView` property to your header file, and the associated `@synthesize tableView;` statement in the implementation. Don't forget to set this property back to `nil` (`self.tableView = nil`) in your `dealloc` for good memory managment
- Link your `UITableView` instance in InterfaceBuilder to this newly created IBOutlet.

Thus you still have a UITableView but this won't be the main view that takes all your screen; instead you can layout your tableView like you want and make it take only a part of your screen, and position the UISearchBar above it.

Another approach would be to use the `UISearchDisplayController` to manage your UISearchBar.

Comment: Ok, is it a big hassle to convert my old UITableViewController to a UIViewController with a tableview? Are there any samples which could guide me? Or is it just UIViewController with adding tableview delegates ?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you every details. Very simple to convert from one form to another.

Comment: a uitableviewcontroller gives you more functionality automatically. e.g. the resizing of the view, when a keyboard appears. its not the best solution to switch to uiviewcontroller.

Comment: With storyboard's support of static and dynamic table view content, you _must_ use a UITableViewController, so this solution doesn't work well. I've had success in the past creating a containing view in -viewDidLoad (in my UITVC subclass), and tricking the base class into looking at the embedded tableView, but trying this today had other issues I'm still working out.