# GADBannerView scroll with UITableView IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to fix the GADBannerView at the bottom of UITableView, the banner shows at the end of the table after scrolling.
[image]

Comment: simply do one thing change UITableView type grouped to plain and add GADBannerView in footer of table view

Comment: Tejas Ardeshna, its not working for me

Comment: Please paste your code so we can get batter idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link. It is not possible you have to use a tableview inside a view controller which is better, than you can add a view to view of uiviewcontroller and constrain it at the bottom of view because than tableview is separate view inside main view.

Original answer is below.

[Add subview to tableview which doesn't scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379934/add-subview-to-tableview-which-doesnt-scroll)